# Difference between two lists recursively

Tags: c, list, linked-list

The exercise I am trying to do, asks me to, given two lists (L1 and L2) without duplicates inside them, create a third list with the elements present only in L1.

The first way that I thought of to solve the problem is to take every single node of the list L1 and compare it with the whole list L2, if the node is not present then I add it to the new list that I have to build.
My problem is that I don't understand how to process this step.

I have understood the basic cases of the exercise. If L1 is empty, return NULL (for example). If L1 is not empty, but L2 is empty, then I simply return L1.

Example:

L1: 15->13->2->3->70->100

l2: 3->13->5->27->100->101

Output:

L3: 15->2->70

This is my attempt:

```
//struct
struct data 
{
  int d;
  struct data d;
};
typedef struct data Node;

//create the list
Node *creat_list() {

    Node *lis, *p, *last;
    int x;

    printf("\n Insert new data: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if(x <= 0)
    {
        lis = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        last = newnode();

        lis = last;
        last->d = x;
        last->next = NULL;

        printf(" Insert new data: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        while(x > 0)
        {
            p = newnode();
            p->d = x;
            p->next = NULL;
            last->next = p;
            last = p;
            printf(" Insert new data: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);

        }
    }
    return (lis);
}

Node *list_difference(Node *l1, Node *l2) {

    Node *l3;

    if (l1 == NULL) return NULL;

    if (l1 != NULL && l2 == NULL) return l1;

    if (l1 != NULL && l2 != NULL)
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
    return l3;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the lists (or sort copies of the original lists)?  That would improve the performance.  What you outline should work, but is slow — it has a time complexity O(length(L1) * length(L2)).  It won't matter if your lists are expected to be short (tens of elements, or less); it will if they're expected to be long (thousands of elements).

Comment: Note that you don't need to test for `l1 != NULL` after you return `NULL` when `l1 == NULL`.  Similarly with testing `l2 != NULL` after you've returned when `l2 == NULL`.

Comment: Presumably, you need to establish a loop over all the elements of `L1`.  For each element, you run a loop over all the elements of `L2` and compare the element of `L2` with the current element of `L1`.  If you find a match in `L2`, you terminate the inner loop and move onto the next element in the outer loop.  If you don't find a match, you add the element of `L1` to `L3`, and then move onto the next element in the outer loop.

Comment: It's hard to see the relevance of recursion here unless the two input lists are in fact sorted.

Comment: The case `l1 == l2` should be handled!!!

Comment: Your `struct data` declaration is incorrect; in C, a structure cannot contain a member that is of its own type, only of a pointer to its own type: `struct node { ... struct node *next };` . Mind the `*`.